# enable text field when something is typed in another the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
 <label for='password' >password </label><br/>
                <input type="password"  name="password1" placeholder="Password" /><br />

      <label for='password2' >repeat password</label><br/>
      <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password (repeat)" disabled="true"  /><br />
```

How can I do something like this:

When the `text field` is empty the second `text field`  should be disabled (disabled="disabled").
When something is typed in the text field to remove the disabled attribute.

and this is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
     $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: ok I will post it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootply** : http://jsfiddle.net/B56CZ/

**HTML** :

```
 <label for='password' >password </label><br/>
                <input type="password"  name="password1" placeholder="Password" /><br />

      <label for='password2' >repeat password</label><br/>
      <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password (repeat)" disabled="true"  /><br />
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //$('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled',true); // <--- Stupid, to comment
     $('input[type="password"]').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $('input[type="password"]').last().prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('input[type="password"]').last().prop('disabled', true);
        }
     });
 });
```

**Comment** :

You don't have `input[type=text]`, only `input[type=password]` so I think you want to disable the second input...

Comment: @Abeer Don't forget to accept the answer to close the post ^^ ( or wait for better answer ) I see your new to SO

Comment: this is the best answer for me :p

Comment: can I use the text field name instead of the input type?? 
 password2.last().prop('disabled', false);

Comment: Yes : $('input[name="password2"]')       http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/